# How to show a menu when left clicking a cell in ng-grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I am trying to have the same menu items appearing when you click a cell (either right or left click it should not matter).

I have been able to do the right click using "getContextMenuItems".

I have been trying to do the left click by calling "getContextMenuItems" when there is a click (onCellClicked). Using the Following code:

```
 onCellClicked(event: CellClickedEvent): void {
    this.getContextMenuItems(event);
  }
```

I can see that the getContextMenuItems is happening but the popup menu is not showing up. anyone know why?

Comment: try using CellMouseDownEvent

Comment: I tried but same error. Whenever I left click, it never displays the menu

Answer (score 1):

Solved this by doing the following:

```
  onCellClicked(params: any): void {
    const rowIndex = params.rowIndex;
    const rowNode = params.node;
    const column = params.column;
    const mouseEvent = params.event;
    const value = params.value;
    const cell = params.api.context.beanWrappers.rowRenderer.beanInstance.rowCompsByIndex[rowIndex].getRenderedCellForColumn(column);
    cell.beans.contextMenuFactory.showMenu(rowNode, column, value, mouseEvent);
  }
```